# (discord.js v14) Having issues w/ MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

first of all, I'm new to discord.js v14 so still learning. I'm working on a **level system based XPS and levels** but when I try to fetch level even if its "0" on the database (checked it multiple times) it still fetches it as "1". Btw I have no problem with fetching XP when I try to fetch XP it gives it normally. I tried everything I know and stuck so hard on this rn, would be so happy if you guys help.

**My code that gives XP to the user per message**

```js
const user = require('../schemas/user.js')

module.exports = {
    system: `level`,
    event: `messageCreate`,

    async execute(bot, message) {
        if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
        if (bot.levelCooldown.has(message.author.id)) return;
        let kontrol = await user.findOne({discord_id: message.author.id});
        if (!kontrol) {
            let newUser = new user({
                discord_id: message.author.id,
                xp: 0,
                level: 0,
            })
            await newUser.save();
        }
        var userdata = await user.findOne({discord_id: message.author.id}).exec();
        userdata.xp = parseInt(userdata.xp) + 1
        if (userdata.xp < 1000) userdata.level = 0
        else if (userdata.xp >= 1000) userdata.level = 1
        else if (userdata.xp >= 2000) userdata.level = 2
        else if (userdata.xp >= 4000) userdata.level = 3
        else if (userdata.xp >= 8000) userdata.level = 4
        else if (userdata.xp >= 16000) userdata.level = 5
        await userdata.save();

        bot.levelCooldown.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            bot.levelCooldown.delete(message.author.id);
        }, 5000);
    }
};
```

**User schema**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    discord_id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    },
    xp: Number,
    level: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user)
```

**Code that I fetch user data**

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const user = require('../schemas/user.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'user',
    aliases: ['üye'],
    
    async execute(bot, message, args) {
        var üye;
        if (!args[0]) üye = message.member
        else üye = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === message.mentions.members.first().id)
        if (!üye) üye = message.member
        let kontrol = await user.findOne({discord_id: üye.id});
        if (!kontrol) {
            let newUser = new user({
                discord_id: üye.id,
                xp: 0,
                level: 0,
            })
            await newUser.save();
        }
        var userdata = await user.findOne({discord_id: üye.id}).exec();
        var hedef;
        var kalan;
        if (userdata.level = 0) {
            hedef = 1000
            kalan = parseInt(hedef) - parseInt(userdata.xp)
        } else if (userdata.level = 1) {
            hedef = 2000
            kalan = parseInt(hedef) - parseInt(userdata.xp)
        } else if (userdata.level = 2) {
            hedef = 4000
            kalan = parseInt(hedef) - parseInt(userdata.xp)
        } else if (userdata.level = 3) {
            hedef = 8000
            kalan = parseInt(hedef) - parseInt(userdata.xp)
        } else if (userdata.level = 4) {
            hedef = 16000
            kalan = parseInt(hedef) - parseInt(userdata.xp)
        } else if (userdata.level = 5) {
            hedef = '?'
            kalan = 'Yakında'
        }
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(bot.config.color)
            .setAuthor({name: üye.user.tag, iconURL: üye.user.avatarURL()})
            .setThumbnail(üye.user.avatarURL())
            .setDescription(`**〉Genel bilgiler** \n**ID:** ${üye.id} \n**Avatar:** [Tıkla](${üye.user.avatarURL()}) \n*(Olum buraya ne koysam bilmiyorum amk önerin bir şeyler bana -Grkm)* \n\n**〉Seviye bilgileri** \n**Seviye:** ${userdata.level} \n**XP:** ${userdata.xp}/${hedef} \n\`Sıradaki seviye için ${kalan} xp gerekiyor\``)
            message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    },
};
```

**Output**
[User command (command that fetches user data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYmCo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements seem to be incorrect.  They are assigning a value to `userdata.level` (after it is retrieved) as opposed to checking its value.

So the following:

```
        if (userdata.level = 0) {
```

Should have an additional `=`, such as:

```
        if (userdata.level == 0) {
```

And repeat for the remainder of the `else if` statements.

You could consider using a `switch` statement there instead but that's an aside.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after a few more changes my code works now!